# How to calculate the probability that something will happen **multiple** times over the course of X attempts.

Tags: probability

I want to figure out how to calculate this properly, everywhere I've checked only explains how to calculate something happening ONCE after X attempts. I want to figure out how to calculate it for example: A 4% chance of it happening and you had it happen 4 times in 10 attempts, how do I calculate what the probability of that happening was? Assume that the chance of it happening doesn't change at all for each attempt, i.e. it doesn't get more likely when you fail and doesn't get less likely if you succeed, it's chance remains the same.

Comment: You use the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)

Comment: @Henry Thank you very much that is exactly what I'm looking for